# How to convert Real to Int?

Tags: sml, smlnj

Let's say I have 0.0 how do I convert it to 0?

I know that I can use `Real.fromInt(0)` to do the opposite (0 -> 0.0) but what about `Real` to `Int`?

In the SML documentation I read about a function `toInt`, but there was no example so I probably use it in the wrong way.

I tried this:

`Real.toInt(a)`
`val a Real.toInt;`

Both are wrong...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Real.toInt` has type `IEEEReal.rounding_mode -> real -> int` so it requires that you specify a rounding mode. For example:

```
Real.toInt IEEEReal.TO_NEAREST 1.2;
```

evaluates to `1`.

There is almost no reason to use `Real.toInt` in everyday programming. Instead, just use one of `round, floor, ceil, trunc` -- functions which correspond to the 4 rounding modes of `TO_NEAREST, TO_NEGINF, TO_POSINF, TO_ZERO` respectively. In other words, rather than use `Real.toInt IEEEReal.TO_NEAREST 1.2`, just use `round 1.2`. Of the four functions, `trunc` corresponds to how `int()` works in Python (and other languages), so is probably the most familiar one.

The only time that I can see for using `Real.toInt` is if you want to experiment with how different rounding modes affect a calculation. Unless you use a variable for the rounding mode which takes on different values in different calls, it is more readable to use one of the four conversion functions which have a hard-wired rounding mode.